# PhoneGap Android lock screen rotation with external web page

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, screen-rotation

I want to disable screen rotation and use landscape always and use full screen always.

I tried

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

and

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Both of them works on the first web page (which includes jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap). This is the first page:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

It is full screen and will not rotate the screen. In the `index.html`, there is a link to game.html (which includes PhoneGap but not jQuery Mobile):

```
<a href="game.html" data-transition="slide" rel="external">
```

But when in `game.html`, it is not full screen and screen will rotate.

Any guess what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by loading url in Java code rather than JavaScript.

Here's how to do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    private JsHelper jsHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        jsHelper = new JsHelper(this);
        super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(jsHelper, "JsHelper");

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}

public class JsHelper {
    private MainActivity activity;

    public JsHelper(MainActivity act) {
        activity = act;
    }

    public void goToHtml(String url) {
        activity.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/" + url);
    }
}
```

In `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func() {
        window.JsHelper.goToHtml("game.html");
    }
</script>
<a href="#" data-transition="slide" rel="external" onclick="func()">
```

Hope this can help others.